# Sending strings to BPF Map Space and printing them out

Tags: bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I have a small txt file that I would like to write to BPF here. Here is what my python code looks like for BPF but I am unable to print out anything as of now. I keep ending up with a Failed to load program: Invalid argument with a bunch of register errors. As of now my string basically says hello, world, hi

```
BPF_ARRAY(lookupTable, char, 512);
int helloworld2(void *ctx)
{
    //print the values in the lookup table
    #pragma clang loop unroll(full)
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        char *key = lookupTable.lookup(&i);
        if (key) {
            bpf_trace_printk("%s\n", key);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Python code:

```
b = BPF(src_file="hello.c")

lookupTable = b["lookupTable"]
#add hello.csv to the lookupTable array
f = open("hello.csv","r")
file_contents = f.read()
#append file contents to the lookupTable array
b_string1 = file_contents.encode('utf-8')
b_string1 = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b_string1)
lookupTable[0] = b_string1
f.close()

b.attach_kprobe(event=b.get_syscall_fnname("clone"), fn_name="helloworld2")
b.trace_print()
```

I have the error linked in this pastebin since it's so long:
[BPF Error](https://pastebin.com/Cmf3EWRM)

One notable error is the mention of infinite loop detected which is something I would need to check out.

Comment: Did you check that clang actually unrolled the loop (`bpftool prog dump xlated <prog>` once loaded, or `llvm-objdump -S <objfile>` but you won't have the object file with bcc)? I suspect it won't, because you pass a pointer to `i` to `lookupTable.lookup(&i)`, meaning that the value in `i` could change inside of the loop, and you _could_ potentially have this infinite loop. The lookup helper is read-only of course, but clang is not aware of that.

Comment: Clang was actually not able to unroll the loop due to the nature of sending a pointer to lookup. @Pchaigno's solution of having an intermediary value seems to work great in making it actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `i` is passed by pointer in `bpf_map_lookup_elem`, so the compiler can't actually unroll the loop (from its point of view, `i` may not linearly increase).

Using an intermediate variable is enough to fix this:

```c
BPF_ARRAY(lookupTable, char, 512);
#define MAX_LENGTH 1
int helloworld2(void *ctx)
{
    //print the values in the lookup table
    #pragma clang loop unroll(full)
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        int k = i;
        char *key = lookupTable.lookup(&k);
        if (key) {
            bpf_trace_printk("%s\n", key);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Seems to have fixed my loop but nothing prints out sadly :(

Comment: Did you check that your map is properly filled? How do you check for the output, do you `cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe`?

Comment: I was able to get an output but there seems to be an arbitrary size limit per character within BPF Array that I have to resolve.